# How find this real value $x+y+z $ if such this equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, rational-functions, symmetric-functions

> let $x,y,z>0$ and such
>   $$\begin{cases}
> \dfrac{x}{xy-z^2}=-\dfrac{1}{7}\\
> \dfrac{y}{yz-x^2}=\dfrac{2}{5}\\
> \dfrac{z}{zx-y^2}=-3
> \end{cases}$$
>   show  that: $$x+y+z=6$$

Comment: @Amzoti [Wolfram alpha finds *only* two](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2F%28xy-z^2%29%3D-1%2F7%2C+y%2F%28yz-x^2%29%3D2%2F5%2C+z%2F%28xz-y^2%29%3D-3) . But yes, there are two different real values of $x+y+z$

Comment: One has negative $y$.

Comment: I wonder if this can be interpreted using something like Cramer's rule. The numerators are all denominators of symmetric matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ones first impression is that this is a set of three quadratic equations. So if we would proceed by eliminating two of the three variables, we would get a higher order equation that presumably can not be solved. However, in this case the functions are such that we can side-step these complications. With a nice trick we can work with linear equations!

$xy - z^2 = P  x$

$yz - x^2 = Q  y$

$zx - y^2 = R  z$

Subtract these equations from each other (e.g. the second from the first). This yields:

$(x - z)  S = P  x - Q y$

$(y - x)  S = Q  y - R z$

$(z - y)  S = R  z - P x$

where we have defined $S = x + y + z$. We now proceed as if $S$ an adjustable parameter, and solve the set of $3+1$ linear equations (of which one can be omitted, since it depends on the other two). The final result is:

$x = (S^2 - QS + QR) C$

$y = (S^2 - RS + RP) C$

$z = (S^2 - PS + PQ) C$

where $C = \frac S  {3S^2 - (P+Q+R)S + QR + RP + PQ}$

Inserting $P = -7, Q = 5/2, R = -1/3$, we find all sets of values $(x, y, z)$ in terms of $S$. In principle $S$ can range from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. But if we are only interested in positive solutions, than we must restrict $S$ to values equal to or larger than $5/4 + (1/12)\sqrt{345}$. This comes down to $S \implies 2.797848$. There is one solution in terms of natural numbers: $x = 1, y = 2, z = 3$.